# Characters repeating with one keypress on Windows 7 in remote session

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

When I press the **´** on my keyboard **once**, it actually results in **´´** (twice).

I am therefore not able to write accents like **á** because I end up with **´´a** instead.

I have tried to switch between keyboard layouts and languages but the problem persists.

When I open Notepad/Editor in the remote session, `á` creation works fine, but with any office Product or IE...well `´´a`.

I'm on Windows 7 running a Remote session. When I log out of the session the problem goes away. The Office Products mentioned are 2007.

EDIT: This happens with **`** and **^** as well.

Comment: Is this `´` character the only character that has this problem?

Comment: Nope: ´ ^ and `